# How to create a blockchain network on a LAN with other computers as nodes or participants?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, ethereum, ibm-blockchain

I have been exploring blockchain technologies for a while now. I have worked in particular with hyperledger, ethereum and quorum. Through all of these i was able to set up a test blockchain with mock local accounts. How would I be able to set up a blockchain on my local LAN ? with possibly 13 computers as participants ?

Any good starting points ?

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a private ethereum network in your LAN by the using the following steps

1. Create a boot node on Computer 1. This will help other nodes to find
   each other in the network else you will have to attach each and
   every peer manually
2. Create a peer node on Computer 2 and attach to the bootnode on Computer 1.
3. Create peer nodes on the remaining 11 computers and attach to the boot node.

Once set up, you can create accounts on any of the nodes as per your use case.

Refer to the following links for creating a private network using boot node
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Private-network
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Setting-up-private-network-or-local-cluster

There is also a good document on Dzone for creating private ethereum network: https://dzone.com/refcardz/getting-started-with-etherium-private-blockchain?chapter=1